# Value based on percentage doughnut char.js

Tags: spring

I want to show a number if doughnut charts in my application. Lets say for example it's based on a number of flights at a airfield.

There are 800 flights in the next 4 hours. I want to have 4 doughnut charts displaying data.

- Number of flights getting ready in the next 30 minutes
- Number of flights getting ready in the next 5 minutes
- Number of flights ready now
- Number of flights that are delayed

I'm using chart.js to create the donuts but as far as I can see I can only use static numbers:

```
this.data = {
    datasets: [
        {
            data: [
                300,
            ],
            backgroundColor: [
                '#FF6384',
            ],
            hoverBackgroundColor: [
                '#FF6384',
            ]
        }]
};
```

This fills the whole chart. I'm thinking there's 2 ways to solve this problem:

1. Chart.js supports some kind of max value (800) and based on the actual number (300) fills the chart based on that ratio.
2. I could use 2 values in the data array. One is the actual number of flights (300) and the other is the difference to the max value (500) = 800.

But I can't use variable values in an array:

```
this.data = {
    datasets: [
        {
            data: [
                this.number1,
                this.number2
            ],
            backgroundColor: [
                '#FF6384',
                '#36A2EB'
            ],
        }]
};
```

Are undefined.

Answer (score 0):

By pulling the this.data object out of the constructor and building it in a function I can calculate the correct values.

```
constructor() {
    this.calcArray(500);
}

calcArray(value: number) {
    const difference = Math.abs(this.max - value);

    this.data = {
        datasets: [
            {
                data: [
                    difference, value
                ],
                backgroundColor: [
                    '#FF6384',
                    '#36A2EB'
                ],
                hoverBackgroundColor: [
                    '#FF6384',
                    '#36A2EB'
                ]
            }]
    };
}
```

So might need to make this a class so I can use it for multiple values.